# RAD StudioにインストールしたComPort Libraryがコンポーネントパレットに出てこない

Tags: c++

embarcadero RAD Studio 10.3でプログラミングを行っています。
RS-232Cポート通信を行いたいため、COMポート通信用のコンポーネントの

https://sourceforge.net/projects/comport/
こちらのサイトから”comport411f”

というのをダウンロードして、RAD Studio用の

sourceフォルダの

CPortLibDXE.dpk
DsgnCPortDXE.dpk

この2つのプロジェクトを開いて、それぞれコンパイルを実行して、DsgnCPortDXE.dpkでインストールを行ったところ、

ツール→オプション→IDE→コンポーネントツールバー
ここの一覧に
”CPortLib”

これが追加されたのを確認できたのですが、実際のコンポーネントパレットの中にこのコンポーネントが表示されません。

このような場合に、確認すべき設定や修正などをご教示頂きますようお願い致します。

## （2019年11月17日追記）

現在も原因を調査中です。
少し気になることがあるので追記させて頂きます。
RAD Studio 10.3を起動して、新規プロジェクトを作成してCPortLibDXE.dpkを読み込んだ時に

> ＊フォームの読み取り時にエラーが発生しました ComSetupFrm＊
>   クラス TComComboBoxが見つかりません。エラーを無視して続行しますか？
>   注意を無視すると、コンポーネントまたはプロパティが失われる可能性があります。

このようなエラーメッセージボックスが表示され、”無視”、”キャンセル”、”すべて無視”
この3つのコマンドがでるような状態で、”全て無視”を実行しています。

そのあとの

CPortLibDXE.dpk
DsgnCPortDXE.dpk

この2つのプロジェクトのビルドは正常に完了していますが、コンポーネントパレットには”CPortLib”が表示されない状態です。

Comment: 単なる感想なのですが、繰り返される質問を読む限り、数々の障壁を乗り越えてコンパイル成功に辿り着いたとしてもまともに動作するとは思えないのですが…。

Comment: こんな記事が参考になりそうです。[ComPort Libraryの導入](http://yuukiwogousei.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-109.html), [ComPort Library version 4.11f install in RAD Studio XE2-XE8 or 10 Seattle](https://sourceforge.net/p/comport/discussion/261327/thread/f4cfe7af/) つまり`sourceforge`の最新リリース版は、まだRAD Studio 10が出ていない時のものだったのでしょう。ただし、この版もRAD Studio 10 Seattle対応なので、RAD Studio 10.3 Rioには対応していない可能性がありますが、その場合は自分で何とかするしか無いでしょうね。

Comment: 皆さんありがとうございます。教えて頂いた導入方法のサイトを見ながらやってみたところ、ComPortをインストールできました。パレットにも表示され貼り付けられるようになりました。
ただ、コンポーネント追加もいろいろあるのですね・・・（＾＾；

Comment: @nordsynth さん、RAD Studioのノウハウは少なそうですので、このサイトのあなたの質問関連だけでも、やったこと・出来た結果を自己回答の形で公開していただけると良い情報源になるでしょう。

Comment: @kunif さん　ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決できました。

[ComPort Libraryの導入](http://yuukiwogousei.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-109.html)
[ComPort Library version 4.11f install in RAD Studio XE2-XE8 or 10 Seattle](https://sourceforge.net/p/comport/discussion/261327/thread/f4cfe7af/)

こちらに記載のあった内容のインストール方法で使えるようになりました。